# Why do I have an error on my shader on mobile and tablet?

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, shader, react-three-fiber

I am posting today to get your opinion on a bug that bothers me a lot.

I have a Three js scene with plans that display my projects ([www.louiscavecchi.fr](https://www.louiscavecchi.fr)).

Here is my shader

```
 const WaveShaderMaterial = shaderMaterial(
  {
    uTime: 0,
    uColor: new THREE.Color(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
    uTexture: new THREE.Texture()
  },
  glsl`
    precision mediump float;
 
    varying vec2 vUv;
    varying float vWave;

    uniform float uTime;

    #pragma glslify: snoise3 = require(glsl-noise/simplex/3d.glsl);

    void main() {
      vUv = uv;
      vec3 pos = position;
      float noiseFreq = 2.0;
      float noiseAmp = 0.4;
      vec3 noisePos = vec3(pos.x * noiseFreq + uTime, pos.y, pos.z);
      pos.z += snoise3(noisePos) * noiseAmp;
      vWave = pos.z;

      gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(pos, 1.0);  
    }
  `,
  glsl`
    precision mediump float;

    uniform vec3 uColor;
    uniform float uTime;
    uniform sampler2D uTexture;

    varying vec2 vUv;
    varying float vWave;

    void main() {
      float wave = vWave * 0.01;
      vec3 texture = texture2D(uTexture, vUv + wave).rgb;
      gl_FragColor = vec4(texture, 1.0); 
    }
  `
);

extend({ WaveShaderMaterial });
```

My shader works fine on pc, but when I resize my window with less than 1200px width I get this error

```
 THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error:  0 35715 false gl.getProgramInfoLog invalid shaders THREE.WebGLShader: gl.getShaderInfoLog() vertex
ERROR: 0:62: 'out' : syntax error
1: #version 300 es
2: #define attribute in
3: #define varying out
4: #define texture2D texture
5: precision highp float;
6: precision highp int;
7: #define HIGH_PRECISION
8: #define SHADER_NAME ShaderMaterial
9: #define VERTEX_TEXTURES
10: #define GAMMA_FACTOR 2
11: #define MAX_BONES 0
12: #define BONE_TEXTURE
13: uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
14: uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
15: uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
16: uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
17: uniform mat3 normalMatrix;
18: uniform vec3 cameraPosition;
19: uniform bool isOrthographic;
20: #ifdef USE_INSTANCING
21:     attribute mat4 instanceMatrix;
22: #endif
23: #ifdef USE_INSTANCING_COLOR
24:     attribute vec3 instanceColor;
25: #endif
26: attribute vec3 position;
27: attribute vec3 normal;
28: attribute vec2 uv;
29: #ifdef USE_TANGENT
30:     attribute vec4 tangent;
31: #endif
32: #if defined( USE_COLOR_ALPHA )
33:     attribute vec4 color;
34: #elif defined( USE_COLOR )
35:     attribute vec3 color;
36: #endif
37: #ifdef USE_MORPHTARGETS
38:     attribute vec3 morphTarget0;
39:     attribute vec3 morphTarget1;
40:     attribute vec3 morphTarget2;
41:     attribute vec3 morphTarget3;
42:     #ifdef USE_MORPHNORMALS
43:         attribute vec3 morphNormal0;
44:         attribute vec3 morphNormal1;
45:         attribute vec3 morphNormal2;
46:         attribute vec3 morphNormal3;
47:     #else
48:         attribute vec3 morphTarget4;
49:         attribute vec3 morphTarget5;
50:         attribute vec3 morphTarget6;
51:         attribute vec3 morphTarget7;
52:     #endif
53: #endif
54: #ifdef USE_SKINNING
55:     attribute vec4 skinIndex;
56:     attribute vec4 skinWeight;
57: #endif
58: 
59: 
60:     precision mediump float
61:  
62:     varying vec2 vUv
63:     varying float vWave
64:     uniform float uTime
65:     //
66: // Description : Array and textureless GLSL 2D/3D/4D simplex
67: //               noise functions.
68: //      Author : Ian McEwan, Ashima Arts.
69: //  Maintainer : ijm
70: //     Lastmod : 20110822 (ijm)
71: //     License : Copyright (C) 2011 Ashima Arts. All rights reserved.
72: //               Distributed under the MIT License. See LICENSE file.
73: //               https://github.com/ashima/webgl-noise
74: //
75: 
76: vec3 mod289_110370617(vec3 x) {
77:   return x - floor(x * (1.0 / 289.0)) * 289.0;
78: }
79: 
80: vec4 mod289_110370617(vec4 x) {
81:   return x - floor(x * (1.0 / 289.0)) * 289.0;
82: }
83: 
84: vec4 permute_110370617(vec4 x) {
85:      return mod289_110370617(((x*34.0)+1.0)*x);
86: }
87: 
88: vec4 taylorInvSqrt_110370617(vec4 r)
89: {
90:   return 1.79284291400159 - 0.85373472095314 * r;
91: }
92: 
93: float snoise3(vec3 v)
94:   {
95:   const vec2  C = vec2(1.0/6.0, 1.0/3.0) ;
96:   const vec4  D_110370617 = vec4(0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0);
97: 
98: // First corner
99:   vec3 i  = floor(v + dot(v, C.yyy) );
100:   vec3 x0 =   v - i + dot(i, C.xxx) ;
101: 
102: // Other corners
103:   vec3 g_110370617 = step(x0.yzx, x0.xyz);
104:   vec3 l = 1.0 - g_110370617;
105:   vec3 i1 = min( g_110370617.xyz, l.zxy );
106:   vec3 i2 = max( g_110370617.xyz, l.zxy );
107: 
108:   //   x0 = x0 - 0.0 + 0.0 * C.xxx;
109:   //   x1 = x0 - i1  + 1.0 * C.xxx;
110:   //   x2 = x0 - i2  + 2.0 * C.xxx;
111:   //   x3 = x0 - 1.0 + 3.0 * C.xxx;
112:   vec3 x1 = x0 - i1 + C.xxx;
113:   vec3 x2 = x0 - i2 + C.yyy; // 2.0*C.x = 1/3 = C.y
114:   vec3 x3 = x0 - D_110370617.yyy;      // -1.0+3.0*C.x = -0.5 = -D.y
115: 
116: // Permutations
117:   i = mod289_110370617(i);
118:   vec4 p = permute_110370617( permute_110370617( permute_110370617(
119:              i.z + vec4(0.0, i1.z, i2.z, 1.0 ))
120:            + i.y + vec4(0.0, i1.y, i2.y, 1.0 ))
121:            + i.x + vec4(0.0, i1.x, i2.x, 1.0 ));
122: 
123: // Gradients: 7x7 points over a square, mapped onto an octahedron.
124: // The ring size 17*17 = 289 is close to a multiple of 49 (49*6 = 294)
125:   float n_ = 0.142857142857; // 1.0/7.0
126:   vec3  ns = n_ * D_110370617.wyz - D_110370617.xzx;
127: 
128:   vec4 j = p - 49.0 * floor(p * ns.z * ns.z);  //  mod(p,7*7)
129: 
130:   vec4 x_ = floor(j * ns.z);
131:   vec4 y_ = floor(j - 7.0 * x_ );    // mod(j,N)
132: 
133:   vec4 x = x_ *ns.x + ns.yyyy;
134:   vec4 y = y_ *ns.x + ns.yyyy;
135:   vec4 h = 1.0 - abs(x) - abs(y);
136: 
137:   vec4 b0 = vec4( x.xy, y.xy );
138:   vec4 b1 = vec4( x.zw, y.zw );
139: 
140:   //vec4 s0 = vec4(lessThan(b0,0.0))*2.0 - 1.0;
141:   //vec4 s1 = vec4(lessThan(b1,0.0))*2.0 - 1.0;
142:   vec4 s0 = floor(b0)*2.0 + 1.0;
143:   vec4 s1 = floor(b1)*2.0 + 1.0;
144:   vec4 sh = -step(h, vec4(0.0));
145: 
146:   vec4 a0 = b0.xzyw + s0.xzyw*sh.xxyy ;
147:   vec4 a1_110370617 = b1.xzyw + s1.xzyw*sh.zzww ;
148: 
149:   vec3 p0_110370617 = vec3(a0.xy,h.x);
150:   vec3 p1 = vec3(a0.zw,h.y);
151:   vec3 p2 = vec3(a1_110370617.xy,h.z);
152:   vec3 p3 = vec3(a1_110370617.zw,h.w);
153: 
154: //Normalise gradients
155:   vec4 norm = taylorInvSqrt_110370617(vec4(dot(p0_110370617,p0_110370617), dot(p1,p1), dot(p2, p2), dot(p3,p3)));
156:   p0_110370617 *= norm.x;
157:   p1 *= norm.y;
158:   p2 *= norm.z;
159:   p3 *= norm.w;
160: 
161: // Mix final noise value
162:   vec4 m = max(0.6 - vec4(dot(x0,x0), dot(x1,x1), dot(x2,x2), dot(x3,x3)), 0.0);
163:   m = m * m;
164:   return 42.0 * dot( m*m, vec4( dot(p0_110370617,x0), dot(p1,x1),
165:                                 dot(p2,x2), dot(p3,x3) ) );
166:   }
167: 
168:     void main() {
169:       vUv = uv
170:       vec3 pos = position
171:       float noiseFreq = 2.0
172:       float noiseAmp = 0.4
173:       vec3 noisePos = vec3(pos.x * noiseFreq + uTime, pos.y, pos.z)
174:       pos.z += snoise3(noisePos) * noiseAmp
175:       vWave = pos.z
176:       gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(pos, 1.0)
177:     }
178:    THREE.WebGLShader: gl.getShaderInfoLog() fragment
ERROR: 0:90: 'uniform' : syntax error
1: #version 300 es
2: #define varying in
3: out highp vec4 pc_fragColor;
4: #define gl_FragColor pc_fragColor
5: #define gl_FragDepthEXT gl_FragDepth
6: #define texture2D texture
7: #define textureCube texture
8: #define texture2DProj textureProj
9: #define texture2DLodEXT textureLod
10: #define texture2DProjLodEXT textureProjLod
11: #define textureCubeLodEXT textureLod
12: #define texture2DGradEXT textureGrad
13: #define texture2DProjGradEXT textureProjGrad
14: #define textureCubeGradEXT textureGrad
15: precision highp float;
16: precision highp int;
17: #define HIGH_PRECISION
18: #define SHADER_NAME ShaderMaterial
19: #define GAMMA_FACTOR 2
20: uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
21: uniform vec3 cameraPosition;
22: uniform bool isOrthographic;
23: 
24: vec4 LinearToLinear( in vec4 value ) {
25:     return value;
26: }
27: vec4 GammaToLinear( in vec4 value, in float gammaFactor ) {
28:     return vec4( pow( value.rgb, vec3( gammaFactor ) ), value.a );
29: }
30: vec4 LinearToGamma( in vec4 value, in float gammaFactor ) {
31:     return vec4( pow( value.rgb, vec3( 1.0 / gammaFactor ) ), value.a );
32: }
33: vec4 sRGBToLinear( in vec4 value ) {
34:     return vec4( mix( pow( value.rgb * 0.9478672986 + vec3( 0.0521327014 ), vec3( 2.4 ) ), value.rgb * 0.0773993808, vec3( lessThanEqual( value.rgb, vec3( 0.04045 ) ) ) ), value.a );
35: }
36: vec4 LinearTosRGB( in vec4 value ) {
37:     return vec4( mix( pow( value.rgb, vec3( 0.41666 ) ) * 1.055 - vec3( 0.055 ), value.rgb * 12.92, vec3( lessThanEqual( value.rgb, vec3( 0.0031308 ) ) ) ), value.a );
38: }
39: vec4 RGBEToLinear( in vec4 value ) {
40:     return vec4( value.rgb * exp2( value.a * 255.0 - 128.0 ), 1.0 );
41: }
42: vec4 LinearToRGBE( in vec4 value ) {
43:     float maxComponent = max( max( value.r, value.g ), value.b );
44:     float fExp = clamp( ceil( log2( maxComponent ) ), -128.0, 127.0 );
45:     return vec4( value.rgb / exp2( fExp ), ( fExp + 128.0 ) / 255.0 );
46: }
47: vec4 RGBMToLinear( in vec4 value, in float maxRange ) {
48:     return vec4( value.rgb * value.a * maxRange, 1.0 );
49: }
50: vec4 LinearToRGBM( in vec4 value, in float maxRange ) {
51:     float maxRGB = max( value.r, max( value.g, value.b ) );
52:     float M = clamp( maxRGB / maxRange, 0.0, 1.0 );
53:     M = ceil( M * 255.0 ) / 255.0;
54:     return vec4( value.rgb / ( M * maxRange ), M );
55: }
56: vec4 RGBDToLinear( in vec4 value, in float maxRange ) {
57:     return vec4( value.rgb * ( ( maxRange / 255.0 ) / value.a ), 1.0 );
58: }
59: vec4 LinearToRGBD( in vec4 value, in float maxRange ) {
60:     float maxRGB = max( value.r, max( value.g, value.b ) );
61:     float D = max( maxRange / maxRGB, 1.0 );
62:     D = clamp( floor( D ) / 255.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
63:     return vec4( value.rgb * ( D * ( 255.0 / maxRange ) ), D );
64: }
65: const mat3 cLogLuvM = mat3( 0.2209, 0.3390, 0.4184, 0.1138, 0.6780, 0.7319, 0.0102, 0.1130, 0.2969 );
66: vec4 LinearToLogLuv( in vec4 value ) {
67:     vec3 Xp_Y_XYZp = cLogLuvM * value.rgb;
68:     Xp_Y_XYZp = max( Xp_Y_XYZp, vec3( 1e-6, 1e-6, 1e-6 ) );
69:     vec4 vResult;
70:     vResult.xy = Xp_Y_XYZp.xy / Xp_Y_XYZp.z;
71:     float Le = 2.0 * log2(Xp_Y_XYZp.y) + 127.0;
72:     vResult.w = fract( Le );
73:     vResult.z = ( Le - ( floor( vResult.w * 255.0 ) ) / 255.0 ) / 255.0;
74:     return vResult;
75: }
76: const mat3 cLogLuvInverseM = mat3( 6.0014, -2.7008, -1.7996, -1.3320, 3.1029, -5.7721, 0.3008, -1.0882, 5.6268 );
77: vec4 LogLuvToLinear( in vec4 value ) {
78:     float Le = value.z * 255.0 + value.w;
79:     vec3 Xp_Y_XYZp;
80:     Xp_Y_XYZp.y = exp2( ( Le - 127.0 ) / 2.0 );
81:     Xp_Y_XYZp.z = Xp_Y_XYZp.y / value.y;
82:     Xp_Y_XYZp.x = value.x * Xp_Y_XYZp.z;
83:     vec3 vRGB = cLogLuvInverseM * Xp_Y_XYZp.rgb;
84:     return vec4( max( vRGB, 0.0 ), 1.0 );
85: }
86: vec4 linearToOutputTexel( vec4 value ) { return LinearToLinear( value ); }
87: 
88: 
89:     precision mediump float
90:     uniform vec3 uColor
91:     uniform float uTime
92:     uniform sampler2D uTexture
93:     varying vec2 vUv
94:     varying float vWave
95:     void main() {
96:       float wave = vWave * 0.01
97:       vec3 texture = texture2D(uTexture, vUv + wave).rgb
98:       gl_FragColor = vec4(texture, 1.0)
99:     }
100:
```

Yes, it's huge... :)
Do you know why do I have this error ?

Thank you for your time and I look forward to your responses!

Louis.

Comment: I just ran your site on Windows Firefox and Chrome and the error did not show up on either browser, even after I scaled down below 1200px.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the error appears once you reload the page with less than 1200px, not when the shader is already loaded :)